# Solr - Adding custom 'non-multivalued' metatags

Tags: solr

I would want to add custom metatags for each of my page to determine its category, where I can do grouping by later on during search.

Hence in my 'schema.xml', here is my definition of my metatag:

```
<field name="metatag.description" type="text_general" stored="true" indexed="true" multiValued="false"/>
```

However, value stored is still multivalued hence cannot be grouped.
Tried restarting Solr to no avail. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First - you'll have to clean out your index and reindex if you're changing a field that has been multiValued to not be multiValued any longer, as the content is still stored as multivalued field in the index (and can contain multiple values already).

Second - as far as I remember, you don't want to use a `text_general` field for grouping, since that field is tokenized and processed (meaning that it's being split into multiple tokens). Use a string field so that the field is kept exactly as it is.

Comment: Hi @MatsLindh . I just tried creating with a new core, and using string as the field type to no avail as well.

Comment: And you've explicitly set multiValued to false? The schema browser shows this as well? Are you using the managed schema or the classic schema factory?

Comment: Yeah, explicitly stated multiValued to false. But schema browser will show that MultiValued is still true. Am using the schema.xml file. Should it be in the managed-schema.xml instead?

Comment: If you have the managed schema file present, then the schema is ]managed through the API](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Schema+API) and not in a schema.xml file. While it's not recommended to edit the managed schema file directly, people have stopped Solr and done just that (if you're not using zookeeper and cloud) - but using the API is preferred.